# Help about a exp(B) interpretation in logistical binary regression

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation

And if the exp(B) = 1 in a logistic binary regression (univariate)? How should I interpret this? (Chi-squared likelihood ratio = 0.008)

Comment: Beta is the log odds ratio, so exp(beta) is the odds ratio..

Comment: So does this mean, in practical terms, that this independent variable has no predictive value? Even with significant p-value?

Answer (score 0):

$\exp B=1$, so the log odds ratio is zero, means there is no effect. You say

> Chi-squared likelihood ratio = 0.008

but also indicates a significant (that is, low) p-value. If that is so, you have a very large sample size ... but in most cases, there will not be practical significance.